# The first element in the Map in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, jstl

How get first element from map on jsp page?
Java code:

```
Map<Long,MyObject> map = ......
model.addAttribute("statuses", map);
```

JSP code:

```
<c:set var="myvalue" value="${statuses[0].value.myfield}"/> //error
<c:forEach var="status" items="${statuses}">
 ....
</c:forEach>
```

How to get the first element to be in the loop forEach?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're trying to identify the first iteration of the `<c:forEach>` loop, then use the `varStatus` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make modification in your Java code not in JSP, it is considered not a good idea since it makes your JSP hard to manipulate. Its easier if you have control in Java code.

In Java:

```
model.addAttribute("status", map.get(0));
```

JSP:

```
<c:set var="myvalue" value="${status.myfield}"/>
```

Comment: Since `get(0)` returns the map value, you don't want `.value`

Comment: get(0) don't get for me first element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this to put element in model:

```
   model.put("statuses", map);
```

And retrieve data in jsp:

```
  <c:set var="myvalue" value="${statuses[0].myfield}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep order in your map, use TreeMap instead of HashMap. They you can get first element via get(0);

Answer (score 0):

We can use `varStatus` to identify the first element in a map.

```
<c:forEach var="status" items="${statuses}" varStatus="_status" >
    <c:if test="${_status.count eq 1}">
        <c:set var="firstElement" value="${status}"></c:set> // Assigns the first element
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps..